# Decompile Android apps built in corona sdk

Tags: android, coronasdk

I have a apk file built with corona. I need to edit the images. I don't have source code. Is there any way to decompile this to get the exact source code?

Comment: Ask the author of the app to give you the source code.

Comment: You probably don't need to get the program logic into source code form to edit the images

Comment: modify other people's programs? Not a cool attitude, the logos of the software developer is through him show his work, so remove the signature of the company/developer from "my point of view" is totally devalue the work of those who created the software.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is bad. Dont do it.
2. This is unnecessary. Modifying images doesnt require getting the code. The best option is to use ApkTool. Heres a quick guide, though I am not sure how old it is. If it doesnt suit you, find something else on Google. http://androidforums.com/esteem-all-things-root/520917-guide-how-properly-decompile-recompile-apks-apktool.html
3. Redistributing the apk after may be illegal. Look into this first.

**Final note - See #1. This is bad. Dont decompile other peoples apps with the intention of modifying and reusing. *Write your own app.***

ApkTool - https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/